# if statement checking for database information, works when it's not supposed to

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make a error checking log in activity, where it will trigger an intent if it detects **the following issues :**

1) if user hasn't signed up (the email he used isn't authenticated with firebase) which is working out well for me

2) if user has signed up but didn't give me any information into the firebase database

My issue is that, for some reason the code i use to check for information in database, works for users even though they have information in the database attached to their UID.

meaning that the intent to tell them to give information will trigger when they already have given information.

```
if(task.isSuccessful()){
    // Checks if user has submitted information in the Essential Information activity
    //Takes the Unique ID(if it is present if not it will tell him to sign up or invalid email) asks the firebase database if he has given information to the database
    reference.child("Users").child(UserUID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // User exists
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                //Displays Toast telling user that their information is saved in the database
                Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "You have data in our database ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //User doesn't have information in the database
            else {
                // Displays Toast telling user he/she needs to sign in into the firebase database
                // User goes to UserInformationActivity to give his/her information
                Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "You need to give Essential Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // 3 second delay
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Goes to UserInformationActivity
                        Intent GoToUserInformation = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, UserInformationActivity.class);
                        LogInActivity.this.startActivity(GoToUserInformation);
                    }
                }, 3000);

            }


        }
        // if the checking got cancelled, likability of that happening is small
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: For people who might not understand what i mean,I mean that a user has information in the database will be taken to give said information into the database again.

Comment: You don't need a `Handler` to create an Intent and launch a new Activity

Comment: @Chisko Yes, that's true, the `Handler` is for a 3 second delay for the user to read what the `Toast` reads

Comment: the toast will stay on the screen for either Toast.short or Toast.long... you dont need a handler for that. the toast will stay unless its time for it to hide.

Comment: @DroiDev removed Handler, same issue persists, handler isn't the issue

Comment: @captindfru i never said handler was the issue. i was just saying u dont need the handler to show a toast.

Comment: @DroiDev I'm sorry for this misunderstanding, but still my question is that why does the if statement get triggered when data exists in the database

Comment: doesnt your if statement say if data exists toast... which part is getting triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to check if the user is signed in?

Directly from firebase...

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
    // check a snapshot to see if there is information....if not, error out.
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```